# I need to find specific rows and count if specified cell in that row has text

Tags: excel, google-sheets

First of all, I'm a rank amateur and just learning the basics of coding.  I apologize ahead of time for any newb mistakes/questions.

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains a number of UI text strings pulled from a program we're developing.  We're going to be translating those strings to several languages.

What I need to do is search to find rows that contains specific translated text for that string (for example Column A is the language, English, Thai, or Mandarin, cells in Column E contain the translated text for that UI element). I need to determine if the tranlation cell (Column E) in that row contains any text.  For example, does Row A3 (Thai) contain text in cell E3.

I want to compare the total number of text strings to the number of strings that have been translated into a specific language (preferrably a percentage number).

I've done a lot of research, and found useful info on COUNTIF, COUNTA, etc.  But I'm getting into the weeds with the more advanced calculations I'm trying achieve and reading forums is not getting me where I need to go.

---

In response to comments, here's some screenshots of what I'm working with.  As you can see, we have a few different languages already translated.  But we have added a few things to the UI, and some of the new text strings need translations added (Chinese, E31 for example).  On the Overview, I've bascially counted all of the English entries COUNTIF (which can serve as the total number of strings).  In the second image, the English column (D2) result would be %100 but some of the languages in the first image are missing translated data.  I'm trying to figure out how to determine how many languages have translated data and compare that to the total number of (english) text strings, I've been requested to display the result as a percentage.  We're going to be adding to this as time goes on, it would be great to set the sheet up to grow with that and give us feedback where we need to add new translations.

Thanks for you patience.  Obviously I have a lot to learn. :)

[image: UI Text Strings]
[image: Overview]

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this is not clear enough.  Can you share an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Screenshot of your data would help here

Comment: Thanks all, I added some screenshots and extra context in the main body.

Comment: can you just share a sample sheet? I have the answer but its far more clear to see a sample of what your actually working with. it can also be dummy data

Comment: Aurielle, thanks so much.  Here's the dummy sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQ_ED_BhNBOeaU9lGVTtBB9IAK2G21SPRRvQf5HwY6w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a pivot table, setting the language (column A) as the rows and then adding the language and the translation (column E) as value fields, in both cases summarising using COUNTA. This will give you the total number of mentions of each language plus the number of translations. You can derive any percentages you need from the resulting table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tom, thanks very much. My concept of this has been forced to expand, and I'm learning a lot!! I created a clean dummy sheet using the identical setup. As you can see it's actually two separate sheets. I learn a lot with reverse engineering, but I'm totally find with "Go here, read this" as I'm trying to learn this for myself.  My main problem is I don't understand how to get COUNTA to work between all three sheets.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQ_ED_BhNBOeaU9lGVTtBB9IAK2G21SPRRvQf5HwY6w/edit?usp=sharing